SSL operation failed with code 1 | Certificate verification failed
So I am getting this error when I am trying to install modules and dependencies for one of my codebases. (composer install for Drupal site)
Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: The "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2022-12-20/2689459-161.patch" file could 
not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
Failed to open stream: operation failed

In Patches.php line 331:

  Cannot apply patch If you don't want to translate your URL alias, the original URL alias won't work with your translations (http   
  s://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2022-12-20/2689459-161.patch)!

This was working fine on my system until last week. I had to remove and reinstall git because it was acting weird with the GitHub Desktop application. During this process, I believe something changed. I saw that C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL folder was not there anymore. I didn't check it before I faced this issue but it seems that this folder is normally present at this location.
I installed OpenSSL as well and this was restored to the same location. But it didn't work for me. Then I thought it could be my company ZScaler tenant issue. I got in touch with that team and got the url whitelisted and also tried unloading ZScaler and eventually uninstalled it. But this didn't work either.
I updated the CA certs as well with the latest ones available and changed the same under php.ini of my XAMPP. That didn't work.
I am looking for some answers on why this issue is being caused and what can be done in-order to move past this. Please let me know if you need any other information regarding this issue.
Any help is appreciated!

May be you have mim in your network?
Can you check the remote certificate from your host using
openssl s_client -connect www.drupal.org:443 |openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer -dates

Connecting to {IP Address} depth=1 C=BE, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, CN=GlobalSign Atlas R3 DV TLS CA 2024 Q2 verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate verify return:1 depth=0 CN=*.drupal.org verify return:1
This is what I got as the response. I am honestly not sure how this works. Does this help identify anything?

I just tried adding a flag and it gave me a different output. Seems like I need to specify the location of the CAfile. I used -> openssl s_client -connect www.drupal.org:443 -CAfile "C:\Program Files\Common Files\SSL\cacert.pem" |openssl x509 -noout -subject -issuer -dates
And this is what the output was -> Connecting to {IP Address} depth=2 OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3, O=GlobalSign, CN=GlobalSign verify return:1 depth=1 C=BE, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, CN=GlobalSign Atlas R3 DV TLS CA 2024 Q2 verify return:1 depth=0 CN=*.drupal.org verify return:1
Does this change anything? @Saboteur

seems trusted certificates configured incorrectly in your web server. not sure how to check if cacert.pem is correct file or your web server see this file, but try to dig in this way

I'm not sure your CA certificate is correct, but you can download the patch file and store it in the 'patch' folder, then reconfigure this file in Composer.json
For you CA file, update the certificate by steps:
Update the CA file of the php environment
Go to url https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2022-12-20/2689459-161.patch
Press F12 (Developer tool), select the Security tab, click View certificate > Details tab > Export > open export file and copy all text
Go to the php.ini file and find the line curl.cainfo = "C:\...\cacert.pem", to locate the cacert.pem file, open the cacert.pem file and paste the file's contents cert you exported before at the end of the file, save it and try running composer again

Thanks @Son Nguyen. Even though I didn't add the certificate to the cacert.pem file, I did download that cert and add it through my registry editor.
I completely removed git, composer, xampp and other dependencies and reinstalled all of them. Going through the process one by one. All of this collectively solved my problem. I can't point out the exact step that solved it. But this is what I did.
Thank you for your help!
